# Add a new password-form programatically to Chromium PasswordStore

Tags: c++, chromium

Is there a way to clear the local passwords store and add a new password-form to it at runtime?

To be more explicit, its ideal if I can accomplish this from the newtab WebUI component that I'm working on, specifically from the instant_service messages handler that I've added to it in order to process various UI aspects of the NTP page.

Let's assume I have the following code:

```
autofill::FormData CreateNewLoginFormData(std::string url, std::string actionUrl, std::string formIdOrName,
  std::string userField, std::string username, 
  std::string pwdField, std::string password) {
  autofill::FormData form_data;
  form_data.url = GURL(url);
  form_data.action = GURL(actionUrl);
  form_data.name = formIdOrName;

  autofill::FormFieldData field;
  field.name = userField;
  field.id_attribute = field.name;
  field.name_attribute = field.name;
  field.value = username;
  field.form_control_type = "text";
  field.unique_id = field.id_attribute;
  form_data.fields.push_back(field);

  field.name = pwdField;
  field.id_attribute = field.name;
  field.name_attribute = field.name;
  field.value = password;
  field.form_control_type = "password";
  field.unique_id = field.id_attribute;
  form_data.fields.push_back(field);

  return form_data;
}
```

How to add this new FormData to the PasswordStore inside chromium?

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer myself.
The idea is to instantiate the password store for the current profile:

```
    password_manager::PasswordStore* password_store =
        static_cast<password_manager::PasswordStore*>(
            PasswordStoreFactory::GetForProfile(
                profile_, ServiceAccessType::IMPLICIT_ACCESS)
                .get());
```

And later in code add a stored password like this:

```
          password_manager::PasswordForm signin_form;
          signin_form.signon_realm = GURL(theLink).spec();
          signin_form.password_value = base::UTF8ToUTF16(thePassword);
          signin_form.username_value = base::UTF8ToUTF16(theUsername); 
          signin_form.url = GURL(theLink);
          signin_form.skip_zero_click = true;
          password_store_->AddLogin(signin_form);
```